# How to disable https on moodle?

Tags: https, moodle

I've recently upgraded my moodle site from 2.9 to 3.4.
Https was only enabled on login page. After the upgrading https is enabled on the whole site. Now some remote scorm packages don't work.
How can I use https only on login page as before?
Thanks in advance!

From modle,org: [Possible issues that may affect you in Moodle 3.4](https://docs.moodle.org/34/en/Upgrading#Possible_issues_that_may_affect_you_in_Moodle_3.4)

> Setting "Use HTTPS for logins" ('loginhttps') was completely removed since it provided false sense of security. If it was enabled before upgrade the whole site will be served via HTTPS protocol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In config.php, adding the following line should prevent https from being forced:

```
$CFG->overridetossl = false;
```

(I've not tested this, but it looks like it should work).